# Starscream delegates not being called

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, delegates

The variable is not nil, I have a good connection and the url is correct but no delegate methods are being called. Also I am implementing WebSocketDelegate

```
 let socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(string: "UrlHere:port/")!)
            socket.delegate = self;
            socket.connect()
            if socket.isConnected {
                print("websocket is connected")
            }

    func websocketDidConnect(ws: WebSocket) {
        print("websocket is connected")
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(ws: WebSocket, error: NSError?) {
        if let e = error {
            print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            print("websocket disconnected")
        }
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(ws: WebSocket, text: String) {
        print("Received text: \(text)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(ws: WebSocket, data: NSData) {
        print("Received data: \(data.length)")
    }

    func websocketDidReceivePong(socket: WebSocket) {
        print("Got pong!")
    }
```

Comment: socket is a member variable of the class I assume, and not a variable local to a method?

Comment: Making it a property fixed my problem. thank you

Answer (score 10):

Socket should be a property or variable of your class to make sure it sticks around.

If you allocate it just on a function stack it will fall out of scope and the delegates will never get called

Here is the code that I have used in my project just in case

```
import UIKit
//import WebSocket
import Starscream

class ViewController: UIViewController,WebSocketDelegate,WebSocketPongDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var wsURL: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var wsConsole: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var wsMessage: UITextField!

    var socket:WebSocket!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        var webSocketObj:WebSocket = WebSocket()
//        webSocketObj.ipAddressText = "10.12.1.101"
//        webSocketObj.portText = "8888"
//        webSocketObj.dataToSendText = "hi"
//        webSocketObj.dataRecievedTextView = ""
//        webSocketObj.connectedLabel = ""
//        webSocketObj.connectToServer()


        wsURL.text="ws://10.12.1.101:8888/"
        wsMessage.text="Hi"
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title="Connect"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled=false
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocket){
     wsConsole.text = wsConsole.text .stringByAppendingString("\n websocket got connected")
         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title="Disconnect"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled=true
    }

    func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocket, error: NSError?){
    wsConsole.text = wsConsole.text .stringByAppendingString("\n websocket got disconnected")
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.title="Connect"
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.enabled=false
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocket, text: String){
     wsConsole.text = wsConsole.text .stringByAppendingString("\n websocket got a message from server:").stringByAppendingString(text)
    }

    func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocket, data: NSData){
        print("websocket received data",data)
    }

    @IBAction func writeText(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        wsConsole.text = wsConsole.text .stringByAppendingString("\n Client sent a message:").stringByAppendingString(wsMessage.text!)
        socket.writeString(wsMessage.text!)
        self.view .endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func disconnect(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
         self.view .endEditing(true)
        if socket == nil{
            connect(sender)
        }
        else if socket.isConnected {
            socket.disconnect()
        } else {
            connect(sender)
        }
    }

    func connect(sender:UIBarButtonItem){
        socket = WebSocket(url: NSURL(string:wsURL.text!)!)
        socket.delegate = self
        socket.connect()
    }

    func websocketDidReceivePong(socket: WebSocket){
        wsConsole.text = wsConsole.text .stringByAppendingString("\n websocket received pong")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Here is the [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-yFxDqROZVpZXNSSEpiZFBqbzQ&usp=sharing) to storyboard just in case if you want